# Specific keyboard button pressed in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, keyboard

Is is possible to call a function whenever a specific button on the keyboard is pressed?

as in:

```
if (textField.spaceIsClicked){
  checkWords();
}
```

Comment: You want to detect when spaceBar is pressed in textField?

Comment: Yes. And the run a function when it's pressed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use delegate function `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` of `UITextFieldDelegate` this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textF: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textF.delegate = self

    }
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string == " " {
            //Run your function here
            println("SpaceBar is pressed")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```